# React/Webpack 4: Advice needed, best practice for loading svgs selectively from a folder

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that represents a "badge". There are hundreds of types of different badges. Every badge is an individual SVG file. The badge component receives a slug for the badge it would need to use. The slug matches the file name. For instance: `best-cheesecake` would hint we need to display `best-cheesecake.svg` in the badge control.

Up till now, I've been loading svg images using:

```
import TestSVG from "../../images/test.svg";
```

and displaying them using:

```
<img height="50px" width="50px" alt="my-test-svg" src={TestSVG}/>
```

**It's critical to understand I'm using WebPack and all images get their filenames hashed.**

My question is about the best practice if my control needs to load one of the hundreds of SVG files. can my `import` dynamically using the filename string as it's given to the control via the `props` **where those files get a hashed filename by webpack**? Is there a better way? Obviously there has to be a way other than importing all SVG files in the folder...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was this:

1. I moved my 500+ badge SVG files from `/src/images`, where I keep all images into `/src/images/badges`
2. I have no explicit reference to any of the badge SVG files in my code so `WebPack` ignores them when creating the `dist` folder (both dev and production).
3. I installed WebPack's `CopyPlugin` and I use it to force the copy of `/src/images/badges/*.svg` into a `badges` under my default `dist` folder (it doesn't care they're not explicitly used in my code)
4. In my code, I can now use this successfully `<img src={"/badges/" + this.props.badgeName + ".svg"}/>`

Answer (score 0):

use require.context concept you can import all the files located in a directory. 
Below is the reference to what I have used earlier -

```
function importAll(r) {
   let images = {};
   r.keys().map((item, index) => { images[item.replace('./', '')] = r(item); });
   return images;
}

const images = importAll(require.context('path/to/the/folder', false, /\.(png|jpe?g|svg)$/));
```

Now you can retrieve a particular image by its file name as below
`<img src={**images[svg]**}  className = {imgClassName} alt = {svg} />`
where svg is filename with extension, ex. file1.svg

Comment: will `importAll` actually load all SVG files in my folder? This could easily get to 500 files. I may have 10 badges per page. Does this mean 10 controls will each have to import 500 files at runtime? Isn't it more efficient to simply dynamically import just the file I need, whose filename I have as a prop?